# Why i can't get msg id without getAttributes()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So usually i can get foreach data with only arrow... But when i use it it return only the first index for the id.

Here the code:

> Model

```
class log_sms_deliver extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'msgid', 'code', 'status', 'date_deliver'
    ];
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'msgid';
}
```

> On Migration

```
Schema::create('log_sms_delivers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('msgid')->primary();
    $table->integer('code');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->string('date_deliver');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

> On Handle Command

```
$logsmsdelivers = log_sms_deliver::where('status', '!=' , 'DELIVER')->get();
foreach($logsmsdelivers as $k => $logdeliver){
    echo $k.' '.$logdeliver->msgid." ".$logdeliver->status." ||||| ";
}
```

but it return

0 2147483647 INVALID SMS ID ||||| 1 2147483647 FAILED ||||| 2 2147483647 FAILED ||||| 3 2147483647 FAILED ||||| 4 2147483647 QUEUE |||||

it should be

0 2147483647 INVALID SMS ID ||||| 1 9415363824 FAILED ||||| 2 9415364207 FAILED ||||| 3 9416372525 FAILED ||||| 4 9417388935 QUEUE |||||

i can get the bottom one with change $logdeliver->msgid to $logdeliver->getAttributes()["msgid"]

But why only the msgid must use getAttribute but not for status ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will automatically be cast to an int

You have a `$fillable` property containing your primary key so I'm assuming you set your own primary key.  If this is the case turn off auto incrementing in your model:

```
class log_sms_deliver extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'msgid', 'code', 'status', 'date_deliver'
    ];
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'msgid';
    // don't auto increment primary keys
    public $incrementing = false;
}
```

See **Primary Keys** in [Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models)

Comment: Ah that's why, so do i need to use protected $keyType = 'string'; too ? Because i set my primary key as a string but it still all number...

Comment: It might be a number, but it shouldn't cast to an int anymore per the docs. I don't think it will break anything to set the `$keyType`.